# Want to display loading bar while load php file in jquery

Tags: jquery

i use a javascript jquery code to call a simple php file to display content. i have a show more link when i click there then new content load. all is working good. i just want to display a loading bar or loading image while getting new data

i want to know how i can display a loading image while calling new content

i have tried following code

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getSummary(1)" class="mini-blk"><i class="icon-refresh"></i> Show More</a>

<div id="summary"></div>

<script>

function getSummary(id)
{
   $.ajax({

     type: "GET",
     url: 'ajax_more.php',
     data: "id=" + id, // appears as $_GET['id'] @ ur backend side
     success: function(data) {
           // data is ur summary
          $('#summary').html(data);
          $('#friendsugMain').hide(); 
     }

   });

}
</script>
```

Comment: This is an exemple -----> [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509711/display-loading-image-while-post-with-ajax

Comment: this is working good the only problem is when first time i click on refresh then loading image not display but when second more then more time then image display good. only first time onclick image not display but new content come

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <div id="summary"></div>

<script>

function getSummary(id)
{
   $.ajax({

     type: "GET",
     url: 'ajax_more.php',
     data: "id=" + id, // appears as $_GET['id'] @ ur backend side
     beforeSend: function(){
        $('#summary').html('<img src="/path to load image/loadimage.gif" />');
        $('#friendsugMain').hide(); // just added to rectify issue that as first time image was not getting displayed
     },
     success: function(data) {
           // data is ur summary
          $('#summary').html(data);
          $('#friendsugMain').hide(); 
     }

   });

}
</script>
```

Comment: this is best i find but the issue is when i click first time on more then load image not display but then again i click then show image. i mean first time click do not display load image but after that display as many as i click

Comment: issue may be that div is affected by other div on page try below -- beforeSend: function(){
        $('#summary').html('<img src="/path to load image/loadimage.gif" />');$('#friendsugMain').hide(); 
     },

Comment: i tried many sites even http://www.askbeen.com and answers.yahoo.com but really here u answer me best. thanks

Comment: abhishek. can i add u on Gtalk or skype as i think u r really one of good developer i meet and i will be honor. can u add me on skype

Comment: yes! why not, you welcome my email id -- asrivastav88@gmail.com

Comment: i got stuck in small prob now. i tested event.target.offsetTop; in iframe normal working good. just not working in my actualy php site. can u come on Gtalk and check my site

Answer (score 0):

Try beforesend and complete events of ajax call, you can just create a image, set it to hidden by default and add something like $("#image").show() in before send and $("#image").hide() in complete event

```
$.ajax({


 type: "GET",
 url: 'ajax_more.php',
 data: "id=" + id, // appears as $_GET['id'] @ ur backend side
 success: function(data) {
       // data is ur summary
      $('#summary').html(data);
      $('#friendsugMain').hide(); 
 },
  beforeSend: function(){
     $("#image").show();
   },
   complete: function(){
     $("#image").hide();
   }
 });
```

[API EVENTS](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/)

Comment: I have edited the code, hope it will give you more clear idea, just create new image tag like <img src = "loader.gif" id = "image" style = "display:none;"/>

Answer (score 0):

with your code :

```
<img id="loading_img" src="smiley.gif" alt="[loading gif]" height="42" width="42"> <!-- change this part with your loading img -->

<div id="summary"></div>

<script>
$('#loading_img').hide();
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $("#loading_img").show();
    }).ajaxStop(function () {
        $("#loading_img").hide();
    });
});

function getSummary(id) {
   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: 'ajax_more.php',
     data: "id=" + id, // appears as $_GET['id'] @ ur backend side
     success: function(data) {
          $('#summary').html(data);
          $('#friendsugMain').hide(); 
     }
   });
}
</script>
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6Cxtw/2/

**This will affect all your ajax query**

Answer (score -1):

I use

```
$("#div").html('<img src="/load.gif" />')
```